# Splitting field containing $n$th root

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

Let $K$ be a splitting field of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose $K$ contains an $n$th root of some number $a$. Then how can we show that $K$ contains all the $n$th roots of unity?

I don't really see any relation between $\sqrt[n]{a}$ and the $n$th roots of unity. Knowing that the former is in $K$ doesn't seem to imply anything about the latter.

Comment: As written, it's not true, $K = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ is the splitting field of (for example) $x^2+1$, it contains eighth roots of $6561 = 3^8$, for example $3i$, but not all eighth roots of $3^8$, it doesn't contain $3e^{\pi i/4}$, for example. You need some restriction on $a$, or the $n$-th root of $a$ that $K$ is assumed to contain.

Comment: To add to @DanielFischer's comment: You almost certainly want $K$ to contain a *primitive* $n^\text{th}$ root of $a$: $K = \mathbb{Q}$ is a splitting field (of $x - 1$), and contains an $n^\text{th}$ root of $1$ for every $n$. But as pointed out, even this is not enough for the claim, as currently stated

Comment: A true statement rhyming to the question:
"If $K$ is the splitting field of $x^n-a$ over $\Bbb Q$ then $K$ contains all the $n$th roots of unity."

Comment: OP has since posted a revised version at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643237/splitting-field-of-xn-a-contains-all-n-roots-of-unity (better, I think, would have been to edit the version here).