# Splitting field of $x^n-a$ contains all $n$ roots of unity

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

This statement is suggested as a correction to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643122/splitting-field-containing-nth-root):

If $K$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $P(x)=x^n-a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, prove that $K$ contains all the $n$th roots of unity.

How to prove it?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg $K$ must contain $\sqrt[n]{a}, \sqrt[n]{a}\cdot\omega, \ldots, \sqrt[n]{a}\cdot \omega^{n-1}$.

Comment: And dividing between pairs, we get $w^j\in K$ for $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1$. Hmm..

Comment: Yes. And next time you want to ask something here, you might think a little bit about it before and try to answer it by yourself. No offense, I just want to remark that by this you learn more than by reading answers by others.

Comment: @ Martin Brandenburg:  your comment assumes knowledge of how much JJ Beck has thought about this question before posting it, and whether he tried to answer the question by himself.  With all due respect, I put to you the question, how did you attain  such knowledge?

Comment: @ JJ Beck:  I found your question to be both well thought out and well expressed, and since I have followed your thoughts on these matters through your linked question, of which this one is a revision, I see there is ample evidence you have given this issue some thought.  Indeed, I upvoted it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $K$ is the splitting field for that polynomial then it contains all $n$th roots of $a$, as you know.  So if $\omega$ is an primitive $n$th root of unity, then the roots of $P(x)=x^n-a$ are $\sqrt[n]{a},\sqrt[n]{a}\omega,...,\sqrt[n]{a}\omega^{n-1}$ just as JJ Beck said.  We can multiply $\sqrt[n]{a}\omega$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a}}$, since inverses exist in $K$.  This give us $\omega \in K$.  Therefore, all powers of $\omega$ are in $K$.  Since $\omega$ was primitive, we get all $n$th roots of unity.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F$ be an *arbitrary* field, $P(x) = x^n - a \in F[x]$ with $p = \text{char} \; F \not\mid n$ and $a \ne 0$, and let $K$ be the splitting field of $P(x)$ over $F$.  Then $P(x)$ splits into linear factors in $K$; that is, there exist $\beta_j \in K$, $1 \le j \le n$, with

$P(x) = x^n - a = \prod_1^n (x - \beta_j) \tag{1}$

in $K$.  Furthermore, since

$P'(x) = nx^{n - 1}, \tag{2}$

we see that $P(x)$ and $P'(x)$ have no common root;  since $p \not\mid n$, $n \ne 0$ in $F$, so the only zero of $P'(x)$ is $0$, which is not a root of $P(x)$.  This implies the $\beta_j$ are in fact all distinct, each from the others.  Now setting $\omega_i = \beta_1^{-1}\beta_i \in K$, we see that $\omega_i^n = \beta_1^{-n}\beta_i^n = a^{-n}a^n = 1$, since each $\beta_i$ satisfies $\beta_i^n = a$.  Furthermore, the $\omega_i$ are distinct, since the $\beta_i$ are.  Thus the $n$ $n$-th roots of unity $\omega_i$ are all contained in $K$.  ***QED.***

Applying the above result to the case $F = \Bbb Q$, we have that the splitting field $K$ of
$x^n - a$ contains all the $n$-th roots of unity for *any* $n$, since $0 = \text{char} \; \Bbb Q \not\mid n$.

It should be observed that the above argument makes no assumptions about the roots of unity lying in $K$; rather, it deduces their existence from that of the distinct zeroes $\beta_i$ of $P(x)$, hence no explicit reference to the complex field $\Bbb C$ is required.  Nor is the primitivity of any of the $\omega_i$ an issue, since we obtain $n$ distinct $\omega_i$ *via* the formula  $\omega_i = \beta_1^{-1}\beta_i$.  And apparently, the essential result is true for *many* fields other than $\Bbb Q$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***