# The order of the splitting field of $x^d+c$ always divide $d\phi(d)$

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, splitting-field

Today I have read that the order of the splitting field of $x^d+c$ always divide $d\phi(d)$. It looks like a nice result, but my text does not give any reference for the proof.
Could anyone suggest me some text where to study it?

Comment: In case $c=-1$...

Answer (score 1):

You might find some help in any treatment of cyclic extensions or Kummer extensions, but quite honestly with a little basic field theory you can probably get there yourself.  The main ingredient is looking at the roots of $x^d+c$ assuming the ground field contains the $d^{th}$ roots of unity, hence the divides $d$, and the assumption about containing the $d^{th}$ roots of unity accounts for the $\varphi (d)$.

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand your hint, not intuitively either. I can understand the $d$ $d^{th}$ roots of $-c$, but where does the $\phi(d)$ come out? (sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: $\varphi (d)$ comes into play because the splitting field must contain the $d^{th}$ roots of unity (assuming the characteristic of the ground field does not divide $d$).  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/643413/254075) for that.  You'll find other relevant content mainly involving the polynomial written as $x^n-a$.  Google site:math.stackexchange.com x^n-a